# Dealing with broken links?

Tags: discussion

A follow-up question to: [Does Stack Exchange have tools to check for broken links?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2073/1006)

As I write this, the Evidence Explained website is undergoing redesign. I need to edit all my answers (and there are **many**) that link to EE's Quicklessons. The EE page is referring people to the Wayback Machine's copies of the old site in the meantime.

The Archive of Quicklessons is available via the Wayback Machine here. https://web.archive.org/web/20150905101409/https://www.evidenceexplained.com/tags/quicklesson

I am willing to use a local Markdown editor to make the changes if no online solution exists. Are there Markdown editors or plug-ins for Markdown editors that would aid in the search for link rot?

Answer (score 1):

On Twitter, one of my contacts recommended the link validator at https://validator.w3.org/checklink.  I've tested it on a few questions and had mixed results.

One downside is that it isn't restricted to just a question or answer. It also tests all the other links like the Hot Network Questions and Related questions. A lot of time is wasted checking links which are blocked due to robots exclusion rules.

It would be cleaner to have a checker that allowed us to specify which part of the page needed checking.